# Statistics customer list with a total purchase value is greater than 50M in 3 months from the time of 31/1 and earlier

Tags: mysql

I have table orders(id, buyerEmail, paymentTime, finalPrice)
Mysql query to list customers purchase worth more than 50 million in the previous 3 months from 31.01.2014?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. What is your question here? I hope you do not just ask the question here because you are too lazy to do your homework yourself and expect someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   buyerEmail
FROM     orders
WHERE    paymentTime BETWEEN '2014-01-31' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY buyerEmail
HAVING   SUM(finalPrice) > 50000000
```